# Pop up message like SO Flag window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do i create a pop up window/message like what you see on this site when you click the flag link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one custom solution. Just creates a div, fades it in, and positions it where you clicked.

jQuery:

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    $('#target').click(function (event) {
        var x = event.pageX;
        var y = event.pageY
        $('<div id="popup">Click to close</div>').appendTo('body');
        $('#popup').css({opacity:0,display:'block',top:y,left:x}).animate({opacity: 1}, 300);
    });

    $('#popup').live('click', function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0}, 300, function(){$(this).remove();});
    });

});
```

CSS:

```
#target {
            cursor: pointer;
            position:absolute;
            top: 100px;
            left: 100px;
            background: orange;
            border: 2px solid red;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        #popup {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: #EEE;
            border: 4px dashed purple;
            position: absolute;
            display:none;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="target">click here</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a jQuery plugin since you've tagged this as jQuery.  [Tooltip](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip) is a nice one that you can use inside an event handler.

[This tooltip plugin](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/) is similar but looks fantastic.

Comment: This looks really really cool. +1. But i am looking for something i can click inside of and select radio buttons. Basically i am looking for the behavior of SO flag button

Comment: The second one I mentioned allows you to use HTML inside the tooltip.